# JSONObject from dot seperated strings

Tags: java, json

I am struggling with a specific problem, that I cannot think of correctly. The following is the problem

I have a **map** with key value like the following, i just used strings here

```
String key = "activate.message.success"
String value = "success"
String key1 = "activate.title"
String value1 = "Good Title"
String key2 = "activate.message.error"
String value2 = "error"
String key3 = "activate.message.short.poll"
String value3 = "This is short poll"
```

I need to build a json like the following

```
{
  "activate":{
       "message":{
         "success":"success",
         "error":"error",
         "short":{
             "poll":"This is short poll"
        }
     },
       "title":"Good Title"
   }
}
```

I could not think of a proper solution for this use case and struggling for 3 hours. I thought of using recursion, but i dont how exactly i could do. Please help with this. I am using java for this, I should use generic JSONObject to solve as there is not POJO mappings. So far I have just splitted the strings using separtor and stored in an another map like the following

```
public Map<String, Object> getJsonObjectFromKeyValueMap(Map<String, String> stringValueMap,
        Map<String, Object> stringObjectMap) {

    for (Entry entry : stringValueMap.entrySet()) {
        String[] keyValueArrayString = entry.getKey().toString().split("\\.");
        int sizeOfMap = keyValueArrayString.length;

        int i = 0;
        String concatString = "";
        for (String processKey : keyValueArrayString) {

            if (i < sizeOfMap - 1) {
                concatString += processKey + ".";
                stringObjectMap.put(concatString, (Object) new JSONObject());
            } else {
                concatString += processKey;
                stringObjectMap.put(concatString, entry.getValue());
                concatString = "";
            }
            i++;
        }

    }
    return stringObjectMap;
}
```

Comment: please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Added this, I have tried to split the string using dot and store it in an another map like the following

Comment: Split the key on a `.`, then for each "value", check if the node (JsonObject) already exist. If not, create it until you reach the end where you put the JsonValue. This is almost what you are doing, execpt that you create a new JsonObject no matter what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's update your data into a proper map :

```
    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("activate.message.success", "success");
    data.put("activate.title", "Good Title");
    data.put("activate.message.error", "error");
    data.put("activate.message.short.poll", "This is short poll");
```

Then, your logic is pretty close, for each node but the last, you create a new JSONObject, for the last, you insert the value.

If you try to build a JSONObject instead of the map directly, you would get a pretty good result already, well somewhat of a result.

The following will iterate a `Map<String, String>` of data.
For each entry, we split the key to getting the nodes.

Then, we just need to move in the `json`, if a node doesn't exist, we create it.
Then, for the last value, create the value.

```
public static JSONObject build(Map<String, String> data) {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    //Iterate the map entries
    for (Entry<String, String> e : data.entrySet()) {
        String[] keys = e.getKey().split("\\.");

        // start from the root
        JSONObject current = json;
        for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i) {
            String key = keys[i];

            //Search for the current node
            try {
                //If it exist, do nothing
                current = current.getJSONObject(key);
            } //If it does not exist
            catch (JSONException ex) {
                //Is it the last node, create the value
                if (i == keys.length - 1) { 
                    current.put(key, e.getValue());
                } //Not the last node, create a new JSONObject
                else { 
                    JSONObject tmp = new JSONObject();
                    current.put(key, tmp);
                    current = tmp; //Always replace current with the last node to go deeped each iteration
                }
            }
        }

    }

    return json;
}
```

And the example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("activate.message.success", "success");
    data.put("activate.title", "Good Title");
    data.put("activate.message.error", "error");
    data.put("activate.message.short.poll", "This is short poll");

    JSONObject json = build(data);
    System.out.println(json.toString(4));
}
```

Ouptut:

```
{"activate": {
    "message": {
        "success": "success",
        "short": {"poll": "This is short poll"},
        "error": "error"
    },
    "title": "Good Title"
}}
```

---

Note : I used an exception to check for the existance of the key, if the map is huge, this could have some impact so you can simply use :

```
if(current.isNull(key)){
    if (i == keys.length - 1) {
        current.put(key, e.getValue());
    } else {
        JSONObject tmp = new JSONObject();
        current.put(key, tmp);
        current = tmp;
    }
} else {
    current = current.getJSONObject(key);
}
```

---

This was created using [org.json/json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20180813)

Comment: Thanks AlexH for this wonderful effort, I will check and will let know tomorrow